# TFS Checkin history migration

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-migration

Please let me know is it possible to migrate all the checkin histories with comments while migrating from TFS 2010 to TFS Cloud?

Answer (score 1):

We migrated out TFS 2010 server to Team Foundation Service using the [TFS Integration Platform](https://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/).  This will allow you to migrate your history to Team Foundation Service one-time or you can configure a bidirectional sync, although the latter is admittedly a much more complicated setup.

Comment: but looking the following link I found that it has some limitation as Check-in notes will not be migrated. Please have a look and let me know. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe

Comment: @TapasMahata You should be able do this by hand afterwards if you need to using the TFS SDK and migrating all check-in comments from your history to the TF Service one.

Comment: @DaveShaw Could you please elaborate how to do this after migration? Is there any option in-build with TFS to do the same?

Comment: No, you will have to develop and application using the TFS SDK to do it. I can provide an example if needed.